# git has problems with squashing commits once there is "Merge branch"

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to squash some commits – current git log looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/knyttl/a2f39cd9376301c78b07

Notice the "merge branch 'master'" – once this shows in the log, the squashing rebase always results in conflicts.

```
git rebase -i ZZZZZZ
```

What I don't understand that this branch has all conflicts resolved, every commit is nicely in the line, so why should these problems emerge?

```
[detached HEAD YYYYY] Typo
16 files changed, 192 insertions(+), 83 deletions(-)
error: could not apply XXXX... Typo

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

Could not apply XXXX... Typo
```

I just want simply all those commits to disappear and create one instead of all of them.

Comment: after a merge git log gives you a flattened model of commits, ordered chronologically, but that's not how they are represented in the commit graph. `git log --graph` may give more insights. also, why not just leave the merge commit alone and squash the rest?

Comment: with `git log --graph` i can see it is more complicated – but from my point of view, i don't really care :-) what I am trying to achieve is to drop `n` last commits and create one which would be equal to `git diff HEAD~n`. My point is – git diff can show me exact diff since particular commit, why `git rebase` can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for what I really wanted – in fact I was just looking for:

```
git reset --soft ZZZ
git commit -a -m "Message for the merged commit."
```

This way I can merge the commits without any necessity for conflict resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still the branch you merge ?

You can `git reset --hard _hash-before-merge_`

then

```
git merge --squash your-branch
git commit
```

that should squash all of your commits into one and the do the merge.